# MySQL Display categories and their count for company in one query

Tags: mysql, select, join, left-join, categories

I'm trying to display the category count, even if 0, for companyId=2 in a single query:

```
categories
+--------+-----------+
| catId  |  catName  |
+--------+-----------+
|   1    |   cat1    |
|   2    |   cat2    |
|   3    |   cat3    |

products
+--------+-----------+---------------+---------+
| prodId | prodName  |   companyId   |  catId  |
+--------+-----------+---------------+---------+
|   1    |   prod1   |       2       |    1    |
|   2    |   prod2   |       2       |    3    |
|   3    |   prod3   |       1       |    3    |

SELECT c.catName, COUNT(p.catId) AS prod_catCount
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN products p ON c.catId=p.catId
WHERE p.companyId=2
GROUP BY c.catId
```

This results in:

```
+---------+---------------+
| catName | prod_catCount |
+---------+---------------+
|  cat1   |       1       |
|  cat3   |       1       |
```

How can I make it result in:

```
+---------+---------------+
| catName | prod_catCount |
+---------+---------------+
|  cat1   |       1       |
|  cat2   |       0       | <-- Shows 0 count as well
|  cat3   |       1       |
```

I thought the left join would take care of that, but it didn't. Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `p.companyId=2` from the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause

```
SELECT c.catName, COUNT(p.catId) AS prod_catCount
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN products p ON c.catId=p.catId AND p.companyId=2
GROUP BY c.catId
```

Comment: So simple, just switch WHERE with AND:) Thanks Walker

Comment: That's a common mistake when using outer joins. You need to put any criteria on the optional tables into the ON clause, or else it negates the outer join.